# Problems with pool size of Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm doing some load tests agains my Spring application and now I'm a little bit confused about the configuration of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

The documentation of the internally used `ThreadPoolExecutor` describes the `corePoolSize` as "the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, [...]" and `maximumPoolSize` as "the maximum number of threads to allow in the pool".

That obviously means that the `maximumPoolSize` limits the number of thread in the pool. But instead the limit seems the be set by the `corePoolSize`. Actually I configured just the `corePoolSize` with `100` an let the `maximumPoolSize` unconfigured (that means the default value is used: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` = `2147483647`).

When I run the load test I can see (by reviewing the logs), that the executed worker thread are numbered from `worker-1` to `worker-100`. So in this case the thread pool size is limited by `corePoolSize`. Even if I set `maximumPoolSize` to `200` or `300`, the result is exactly the same.

Why the value of `maximumPoolSize` has no affect in my case?

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("worker-");
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I've found the solution in the documentation: "*If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full*". The default queue size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If I limit the queue, everything works fine.

Answer (score 23):

I have done some testing on `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and there is three things that you have to understand:

- corePoolSize
- queueCapacity
- maxPoolSize

When you start the process there is no threads in the pool.
Each time a task comes one new executor thread will be created to handle this new load as long the `corePoolSize` is not reached.
When the `corePoolSize` is reached the next task will be shift to the queue and wait for a free executor thread. 
If the load is too high and `queueCapacity` is full, the new executor threads will be created unless the `maxPoolSize` is reached. These additional threads will expire as soon as the queue is empty.
If the `corePoolSize` is exhausted, `queueCapacity` is full and `maxPoolSize` is also reached then the new submitteds tasks will be rejected and called will get an exception.

You have not mentioned the `queueCapacity` of your configuration so it might be set to highest integer number and thus `maxPoolSize` is never getting triggered. Try with small `corePoolSize` and `queueCapacity` and you will observe the desired result.

Comment: Good write. But see the user already gave answer of his/her own post.

Comment: I did not see that, I just joined and searching for questions to answer and I get this one and answered. Is there any way it can be marked as answered. The we will not lose time on already answered questions.

Comment: @SomnathDe your answer was far better in explaining it. Thanks Mate.

Comment: Personall I don't think the design is good enough. Assume I have a queueCapacity=5000, corePoolSize=100, maxPoolSize=300. If the workload is heavy, soon it reaches the 100 busy threads, then the queue increase rapidly until it reaches 5000, only at that time it starts to spawn new executor threads. I think in this example, when queue is filled with 2000 tasks, it should already starts to spawn threads.... say 200 threads as the limit. And if the task size in queue is still growing, it should quickly spawn to 300(maxPoolSize). In this way more tasks are handled promptly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have 100 threads in a pool and you are executing CPU bound code on 4 physical CPU cores, most of your core threads are idle in the pool waiting to be re-used. That is probably why you don't see more than worker-100.

You didn't show us code you are executing in workers, therefore I assume it is not I/O bound. If it would be I/O bound code and 100 of your core threads would be occupied by waiting for blocking I/O operations to finish, `ThreadPoolExecutor` would need to create additional workers.

Try it with `corePoolSize` lower than number of cores on your machine to confirm. Another option is to put `Thread.sleep(1000)` into your worker code and observe how your workers count will be raising.

EDIT:

You suggested to use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` in comment. Notice this section of [Spring Framework docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-executor-types):

> SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor This implementation does not reuse any
>   threads, rather it starts up a new thread for each invocation.
>   However, it does support a concurrency limit which will block any
>   invocations that are over the limit until a slot has been freed up. If
>   you are looking for true pooling, see the discussions of
>   SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor below.

So with `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` you don't have pooling at all and a lot of resources (CPU cycles included) are wasted on creation and deletion of `Thread` objects, which may be quite expensive operation.

So `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` executor type does more harm than good to your load testing. If you want to have more workers, use more machines. It's naive to use only one machine if you want to have accurate load testing.

Comment: If I don't define the thread pool bean the "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" is used automatically. With this with executor (no limits) the results are 3 times better. If I set the core pool size of the "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" to 20, the maximum used threads are 20. With a smaller pool size the result are worse, this can't be the solution!